# how to calculate phase space of velocity and draw a scatter plot in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a vector for velocity of a time series. for example :

```
u=[100,120,150,115,130,115,105,103,108,132,135,121]
```

now I need to calculate Δu and then draw a scatter plot.
something like the picture below.
how can I do that?

[image]

Comment: your definition of Δu is missing here.. is it the difference to the prior velocity?

Comment: Since you seem to be new to Stack Overflow, you should read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
and  [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `Δu = u[i] - u[i-1]`, It is obvious you should use this formula for `u[1:]`.
So just simply use these lines of codes:

```
from numpy import array
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

u = aray(u)
del_u = u[1:] - u[:-1] # This line let you use that formula for all numbers in array except first one.
plt.scatter(u[1:], del_u)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

u = np.array([100,120,150,115,130,115,105,103,108,132,135,121])
du = u[1:] - u[:-1] # the difference between the current and the prior velocity

plt.scatter(u[1:],du)
plt.show()
```